# Getting error on npm run start in blockchain-explorer hyperledger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

**I am trying to use hyperledger's blockchain-explorer for my production network. But when following the instructions I got this error when I started running npm start in the blockchain-explorer directory:**

```
************************************************************************************
**************************** Hyperledger Explorer **********************************
************************************************************************************
./start.sh: 24: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! hyperledger-explorer@1.1.8 app-start: `./start.sh`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the hyperledger-explorer@1.1.8 app-start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/conqueror/.npm/_logs/2022-10-05T02_01_23_907Z-debug.log
ERROR: "app-start" exited with 2.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! hyperledger-explorer@1.1.8 start: `run-s build app-start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the hyperledger-explorer@1.1.8 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/conqueror/.npm/_logs/2022-10-05T02_01_23_940Z-debug.log
```

Can someone tell me how I can fix it. I'm really stuck!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using docker for explorer setup then you have simply set all the paths and config in your cloned repo. And then just need to perform the below commands.

```
1. docker system prune
2. docker volume prune

3. docker-compose down 
4. docker-compose up
```

Comment: Thank you but i'm trying to use codebase!